# OpenLayers - 2.13. getDataExtent() returns null

Tags: json, openlayers, markers

I am working with OpenLayers. I am using Javascript and PHP to achieve the same.

I take the marker positions (on the map) from a database. I returned a JSON object of all the marker positions and looping all of them in my javascript file.

Markers are positioning OK, but in the end when I want the map to be zoomed to the bounds of all the markers, map gets zoomed infinitely. Can anybody give me some help on this topic with preferably some example code.

My code snippet goes this way:

```
$.getJSON('contactDB.php', function(items)
{

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) 
  {
    (function(item) 
    {

      var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(item.lon, item.lat).transform(
          new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
          map.getProjectionObject());

      markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonlat, icon.clone()));


    })(items[i]);
  }
});

map.addLayer(markers);
var newBounds = markers.getDataExtent();
alert(newBounds);
map.zoomToExtent(newBounds);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
layer.events.register("loadend", layer, function() { 
    map.zoomToExtent(layer.getDataExtent()); 
});
```